# DevExpress DropDownButton Problems

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to create a DevEx drop down button. Unfortunately, I'm running into two problems I can't figure out:

1) I can't get the popup menu to skin correctly, i.e. it doesn't skin as "Office 2010 Blue". The code I'm using is shown below:

```
        private void InitializeSendToPricingSheetButton()
        {
            var barManager = new BarManager();
            if (barManager.Controller == null) barManager.Controller = new BarAndDockingController();
            barManager.Controller.PaintStyleName = "Skin";
            barManager.Controller.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            barManager.Controller.LookAndFeel.SkinName = "Office 2010 Blue";

            barManager.ItemClick += HandleSendToPricingSheetClick;
            barManager.Items.AddRange(new[] { new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Foo"), new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Bar"), new BarButtonItem(barManager, "Baz") });

            var popupMenu = new PopupMenu { Manager = barManager };
            foreach (var barItem in barManager.Items) popupMenu.ItemLinks.Add((BarItem)barItem);
            popupMenu.ItemLinks[1].BeginGroup = true;

            dropDownButtonSendToPricingSheet.DropDownControl = popupMenu;
        }
```

2) This button is on a form. If the form loses focus (e.g. I click on Firefox), the pop-up menu still remains on-top. It won't go away until clicked.

Any suggestions would be ***much*** appreciated. Thanks for helping me deal with DevEx insanity.

Answer (score 2):

I have solution to your second question.

You should add drop down button event handler as below:

```
dropDownButton1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(HidePopUp);
```

Handler method should be as below:

```
private void HidePopUp(object sender,object e)
        {
            dropDownButton1.HideDropDown();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you should assign value to the bar manager property as:

```
BarManager manager = new BarManager();
manager.Form = this; // refers to current form
```

Find below link for reference
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q274641

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please make a habit of formatting your code here. This time I did it for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably simpler to use DefaultLookAndFeel

Add this comp to your form and set the theme you'd like to use.
There is no need to set the theme for individual components.

```
defaultLookAndFeel1.LookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle("Office 2010 Blue");
```